# How to create uniform/equal radius bevel

Tags: bevel

I have a cube and I want to apply **Bevel**. When I apply bevel it comes like this:

[image]

But actually I want uniform bevel like below: where radius is equal for all width, height and depth.

[image]

Please tell me how to do that

Comment: Does you object has non-uniform scale?

Comment: Use Ctrl+A in Object mode with the object selected and choose Scale, it's seen in the Properties editor to the right that the scale is non-uniform (likely scaled in Object mode)

Comment: Thanks @Mr Zak, I applied scale, and now I got uniform bevel.